# application freezes on INSERT

Tags: sql-server, insert, freeze

I am calling a stored proc for doing INSERT on a table. The table has primary key defined. It works fine in development environment. But after the application has been published to production server , users are complaining that it freezes occasionally. I tried to replicated the issue using the same data, but works fine. I am assuming that it freezes with many users hitting the same table. We cannot use 'With NOLOCK' statement on INSERT. What could you recommend to fix the issue?

Note: I would also like to mention that all the requests that go through production servers, an alias is sent to an IP load balancer, which depending upon our web farm (4 individual production web servers) direct users to one of the 4 web servers where their session will reside.

Comment: Using transactions could works?

Comment: @Hackerman, So by using transaction there will be no deadlock?

Comment: @Hackerman, Should it be in the application code or in storedproc?

Comment: In the stored procedures using serializable isolation or in the application code checking the optimistic concurrency option.